# RedirectToRoute not working in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am building a somewhat complex ASP.NET MVC website with multiple controllers. In the Index()-method/handler of each controller I perform some validation and redirect to the default route in case of an error so the user gets redirected to the default page of the website when something goes wrong.
However, for some reason the redirect just doesn't work. I use `RedirectToRoute("Default")` to redirect to the default route but somehow the Index()-method of the controller I am currently in just gets called again and no redirect is happening. This results in an infinite loop and at some point the browser displays a redirect error. 
I have the default route defined as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
```

Why does it not redirect to the Index-action of the Home-controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are redirecting to the same route as you are now. The defaults that are specified on the "Default" route only apply when there are no values for "controller" and "action", which is not the case - you are running inside a specific action of a controller.
Probably what you want is to redirect to the root of your app, which is normally where you go to in the first place (your "Default" route seems to indicate that).